# jQuery Mobile Keeps Loading First Page in Multi Page Document When Submitting A Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've been looking for so long to a solution other than `data-ajax="false"` because that didn't work for me.

Anyway, in my Phonegap app, when I use jquery mobile to submit a form, I need to run it through the regular on submit function in jquery to manipulate it some before it goes to the server.

I'm encrypting it for the first time on the phone before it goes to the DB to be more secure.

Anyway, before I needed to switch to the multi page method with JQM, I could submit a form and it would submit no problem.

But, when I changed only the HTML to be a multi page setup, all I get is a refresh to the login screen, the first page, regardless if I'm on that or registering.

Also, in testing, if I try to alert anything, inside the function or no, nothing appears, so that route of testing doesn't work for me.

The most important thing is for me to get the forms submitting.

One more thing, when I put the code in jsfiddle, everything, the alert and all, works perfectly.

So I don't know if it is phonegap or not.

JS Fiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/copilot0910/mVgLJ/

**Code**

*HTML*

```
<h1>Login</h1>

                    <label for="uname">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" value="" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" />
                    <label for="pword">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="pword" id="pword" value="" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login_submit_btn" id="login_submit_btn" />
                </form>
<a href="#register" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini">Go Register</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="register" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                <form id="register_form">

<h1>Register</h1>

                    <label for="uname_reg">Wanted Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="uname_reg" id="uname_reg" value="" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" />
                    <label for="pword_reg">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="pword_reg" id="pword_reg" value="" />
                    <label for="email_reg">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email_reg" id="email_reg" value="" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" />
                    <label for="fname_reg">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname_reg" id="fname_reg" value="" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" />
                    <label for="lname_reg">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname_reg" id="lname_reg" value="" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
<a href="#login" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-inline">Go Login</a>

<a href="#tac" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-mini" data-transition="pop">You Accept our Terms</a>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

*jQuery*

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login_form").submit(function () {
            event.preventDefault();

            alert("Login Alert");

            $("#uname").blur();
            $("#pword").blur();
            $("#uname_reg").blur();
            $("#pword_reg").blur();
            $("#email_reg").blur();
            $("#fname_reg").blur();
            $("#lname_reg").blur();

            var NoHashPwd = $("#pword").val();
            var pwd = hex_sha512(NoHashPwd);
            var usrname = $("#uname").val();

            var loginData = {
                "uname": usrname,
                    "p": pwd
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Not Telling",
                data: loginData,
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (resp.msg === "good") {
                        doGeolocate();
                    } else {
                        alert(resp.msg);
                    }

                    $("#uname").val("");
                    $("#pword").val("");
                    $("#uname_reg").val("");
                    $("#pword_reg").val("");
                    $("#email_reg").val("");
                    $("#fname_reg").val("");
                    $("#lname_reg").val("");

                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

        $("#register_form").submit(function () {
            event.preventDefault();

            alert("Login Alert");

            $("#uname").blur();
            $("#pword").blur();
            $("#uname_reg").blur();
            $("#pword_reg").blur();
            $("#email_reg").blur();
            $("#fname_reg").blur();
            $("#lname_reg").blur();

            var NoHashPwd = $("#pword_reg").val();
            var p = hex_sha512(NoHashPwd);
            var uname = $("#uname_reg").val();
            var fname = $("#fname_reg").val();
            var lname = $("#lname_reg").val();
            var email = $("#email_reg").val();

            var regData = {
                "uname": uname,
                    "p": p,
                    "fname": fname,
                    "lname": lname,
                    "email": email
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Not Telling",
                data: regData,
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (resp.flag === "good") {
                        doGeolocate();
                    } else {
                        alert(resp.flag);
                    }

                    $("#uname").val("");
                    $("#pword").val("");
                    $("#uname_reg").val("");
                    $("#pword_reg").val("");
                    $("#email_reg").val("");
                    $("#fname_reg").val("");
                    $("#lname_reg").val("");

                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

By the way, the extra `deviceready` function is for phonegap, so leave that be. Hasn't caused problems ever.

Comment: 1) use `$(document).on("pageinit", "#pageID", function () { code for this page / handlers etc.. });` instead of `.ready()`. 2) wrap login fields in `form` and use `.on()` e.g. `$("#login_formID").on("submit", function () { reset of code });`

Comment: @Omar the code was trunucated at the top for some reason. I have the form tag. Also, `.on()` didn't help. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgotting the RETURN FALSE; on your submit(); function.

You've placed it inside the Ajax callback, you need to put it on the end of your submit code, like this:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function () {
            event.preventDefault();

            alert("Login Alert");

            $("#uname").blur();
            $("#pword").blur();
            $("#uname_reg").blur();
            $("#pword_reg").blur();
            $("#email_reg").blur();
            $("#fname_reg").blur();
            $("#lname_reg").blur();

            var NoHashPwd = $("#pword").val();
            var pwd = hex_sha512(NoHashPwd);
            var usrname = $("#uname").val();

            var loginData = {
                "uname": usrname,
                    "p": pwd
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Not Telling",
                data: loginData,
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (resp.msg === "good") {
                        doGeolocate();
                    } else {
                        alert(resp.msg);
                    }

                    $("#uname").val("");
                    $("#pword").val("");
                    $("#uname_reg").val("");
                    $("#pword_reg").val("");
                    $("#email_reg").val("");
                    $("#fname_reg").val("");
                    $("#lname_reg").val("");

                    return false;
                }
            });
            return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });
```

Comment: Didn't do it. It still just refreshes back to the login page on both the app and js fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, the "deviceready" event only fires when the DEVICE is ready.
The alerts are working now. For testing use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";
onDeviceReady();

});
```

I took the liberty of error checking your code and making it Lint compliment.
Please find the full code bellow P.S Declare functions before you call them that's way "deviceready" call is at the end.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert, hex_sha512 */

function onDeviceReady() {
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login_form").submit(function () {
        event.preventDefault();

        alert("Login Alert");

        $("#uname").blur();
        $("#pword").blur();
        $("#uname_reg").blur();
        $("#pword_reg").blur();
        $("#email_reg").blur();
        $("#fname_reg").blur();
        $("#lname_reg").blur();

        var NoHashPwd = $("#pword").val(),
            pwd = hex_sha512(NoHashPwd),
            usrname = $("#uname").val(),
            loginData = {
                "uname": usrname,
                "p": pwd
            };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Not Telling",
            data: loginData,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp.msg === "good") {
                    alert("good");
                    //doGeolocate();
                } else {
                    alert(resp.msg);
                }

                $("#uname").val("");
                $("#pword").val("");
                $("#uname_reg").val("");
                $("#pword_reg").val("");
                $("#email_reg").val("");
                $("#fname_reg").val("");
                $("#lname_reg").val("");

                return false;
            }
        });
    });

    $("#register_form").submit(function () {
        event.preventDefault();

        alert("Login Alert");

        $("#uname").blur();
        $("#pword").blur();
        $("#uname_reg").blur();
        $("#pword_reg").blur();
        $("#email_reg").blur();
        $("#fname_reg").blur();
        $("#lname_reg").blur();

        var NoHashPwd = $("#pword_reg").val(),
            p = hex_sha512(NoHashPwd),
            uname = $("#uname_reg").val(),
            fname = $("#fname_reg").val(),
            lname = $("#lname_reg").val(),
            email = $("#email_reg").val(),
            regData = {
                "uname": uname,
                "p": p,
                "fname": fname,
                "lname": lname,
                "email": email
            };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Not Telling",
            data: regData,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp.flag === "good") {
                    //doGeolocate();
                    alert("success");
                } else {
                    alert(resp.flag);
                }

                $("#uname").val("");
                $("#pword").val("");
                $("#uname_reg").val("");
                $("#pword_reg").val("");
                $("#email_reg").val("");
                $("#fname_reg").val("");
                $("#lname_reg").val("");

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";
onDeviceReady();

});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: `deviceready` at the bottom was a good suggestion, but that didn't help. I'm just wondering if it is because jQuery Mobile and having multiple pages is making the problem. That doesn't account for the alert problem tho.